# Perl program to compute average for each column of numbers within file

Tags: perl

This is what I have so far, but the code is only showing contents of column 1.  I'm not sure how to compute columns. I am really new to programming, so this may be an easy question.

```
my $filename = "Q5.txt";

open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "Could not open '$filename'\n";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    $count++;
    @line = $line;
    for (@line) {
      ...
   }
}

print $line[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should suit you

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $filename = 'Q5.txt';

my ($n, @totals);

open my $fh, '<', $filename;

while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  $totals[$_] += $fields[$_] for 0 .. $#fields;
  ++$n;
}

$_ /= $n for @totals;

print "@totals\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! You have no idea how much you have helped me. I have been working on this code for 3 days straight..:)

Comment: Is there a way I can display the total of each column by itself?

Comment: The individual averages are in the array elements `$totals[0]` to `$totals[$#totals]`. `$#array` is always the index of the last element in an array. Sorry, you said you wanted the totals, not the averages. Just examine the array before the line `$_ /= $n for @totals`, which divides all the elements by the number of values. Is there anything you don't understand about the code? I didn't know what to explain.

Comment: Thanks I printed them out by accessing the array's individual elements.

Comment: You may want a loop - something like `print "$_\n" for @totals`